# Filtered Lookup fields. Are they supposed to work an not yet saved records?

Tags: lookup, filters

Althoug I defined a filtered lookup the selection window is not showing anything (no Release records to choose from).

I have the following structure:

[image]

I want to defined a filtered lookup field "Bug found in Release" to the Bug object to let the user only choose Releases from the same Product as the Bug.

I prepopulate the Product relationship on my new page, but the Bug record exits only in memory unless the user clicks Save.

Is the filtered lookup supposed to work here or only when I update existing Bug records.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as you. Assuming that both *Bug Product* (*Bug_Product__c*) and *Bug Release* (*Bug_Release__c*) are custom fields (with Lookups on *Product__c* and *Release__c* custom objects, respectively) on your Bug__c custom object, you should have already defined lookup filter for the Bug_Release__c custom field which would resemble something like this:

> Bug: Bug Product **equals** Bug Release: Product

You can circumvent the fact that your Bug record does not yet exist in a following manner:

First, extend the standard *Bug__c* controller and create a reference to an instance of *Bug__c* object (as the new one which is about to be created does obviously not yet exist):

```
public with sharing class YourBugPageController {
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

    public Bug__c Bug { get; set; }
    public Product__c Product { get; set; }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public YourBugPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // Or whichever logic you use to fetch the product record
        Product = [SELECT Name FROM Product__c WHERE Id = : someId];

        //pre-populate Account on load
        this.Bug = (Bug__c)controller.getRecord(); 
        this.Bug.Product__c = Product.Id;
        stdcontroller=controller;
    }
}
```

Once you have the controller set, use the pre-populated Bug object in your VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Bug__c" extensions="YourBugPageController" id="createBug" title="Bug on {!Product.Name}">

    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock title="Bug on {!Product.Name}" id="pageBlock" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons id="pageBlockButtons">
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" id="cancelButton" action="{!cancel}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Create" id="submitButton" action="{!create}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Lookups Section" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Bug.Bug_Product__c}" /><br />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Bug.Bug_Release__c}" /><br />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            ...
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The only thing left for you to do is to implement custom save logic, which extracts the values and inserts the new record. Hope it helps!